# Tridion CM reports "Couldn't retrieve data from 1 datasources"

Tags: tridion, ugc

When opening various popups in the Tridion Explorer, the message centre displays the message:

```
Couldn't retrieve data from 1 datasources
```

What does this mean, and how can I prevent it?

Edit: Yes - everyone who said UGC was right. In fact, the problem was not with referencing the web services, but that they weren't working correctly. So if you're setting up UGC, make sure you check (with your browser) that the OData services are not just available, but that they respond correctly to queries.

Comment: What version of SDL Tridion are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience that is related to UGC too. However though, it is very much related to Tridion. Namely, when the CME tries to access the CD Webservice to retrieve UGC stats/settings for Components or Pages. If the CD Webservice does not respond, then such an error shows up in the Message Center.

Check your `%TRIDION_HOME%\web\WebUI\Models\UGC\Configuration\DataSources.xml`

Answer (score 5):

The only time I've seen this reported was related to UGC.

It was reported that it appeared to be browser / system related, not a Tridion error.

Taking a wild guess, it may be because of custom errors not being shown on a local system?
If you try to access from a browser on a separate system, do you get the same error?